# What explains the Genie's fate?

Tags: disney, aladdin-2019

In Disney's *Aladdin* (2019), Aladdin wishes for

> the Genie's freedom, and the Genie ***becomes human***.

But why doesn't he just stay a Genie but without the shackles, like in the 1992 version?

Comment: ...so dopes in the audience can go "ohhhh! It was Will Smith this whole time!" ;)

Comment: So, in other words they rehashed _The Little Mermaid_.

Comment: I believe Genie made a comment earlier about how he's kinda done having lived for tens of thousands of years.

Answer (score 8):

It was what he wished for earlier in the film. Clearly Aladdin's magical wish took that into consideration (somehow)

> The Genie looked surprised. “Wow,” he said after a pause. “Nobody’s ever asked me that before. But that’s easy. To be free. To be my own master. **Be human.**”
>   “Why don’t you just set yourself free?” Aladdin asked, confused. Wasn’t that a perk of being all-powerful? Couldn’t you do whatever you wanted?
>
> <sub><sup>[Aladdin: Official Novelisation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1368037119)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 3):

Having *"phenomenal cosmic power"* and having fallen in love with Dalia it stands to reason he chose to remain human to live his life with her.